# Questions on proof of Tutte-Berge formula

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, matching-theory

I am following the proof of Tutte-Berge formula here: [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/tutteb.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Elex/files/tutteb.pdf)

In particular in the second half of the proof
[image]

I have 2 questions

1. How does a matching of size $\frac{1}{2}(|V| - 1)$ imply the theorem taking $ U := \emptyset$ ?  For this to hold true, the number of odd components $G$, denoted as $o(G)$ must be equal to 1.  How is that immediate?  Couldn't it as well be 0 ($G$ has only even components) or $>1$ ($G$ has multiple odd components)?
2. At the last step of the proof, we claim that replacing N by $(N \setminus \{f\})\cup \{e\}$ increases the intersection with M.  However, doing this replace means that some $w \in f = wy \in N$ gets removed from $N$.  Are we assuming that $w \notin M$ or that eventually with successive replacements, we will end up removing some $w' \notin M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, suppose there is a matching of size $\frac12(|V|-1)$: covering all vertices except some vertex $x$.

A connected component cannot contain just half of an edge of this matching:  if it contains one endpoint, it contains the other.

- A component that contains $x$ and $k$ edges of the matching is odd: it contains $2k+1$ vertices total.
- A component that contains $k$ edges of the matching but not $x$ is even: it contains $2k$ vertices total.

Since only one connected component contains $x$, there is only one odd component.

---

For the second question: certainly $w \notin M$, but maybe it is more accurate to say that it doesn't make sense to ask whether $w\in M$. The matching $M$ is a set of edges, and $w$ is a vertex.

The important thing to check here is that $(N \setminus \{f\}) \cup \{e\}$ is a matching. $(N \setminus \{f\})$ is a matching that does not cover $x$ (since $N$ did not) or $y$ (since $y$ was covered by $f$), so adding edge $e = xy$ gives us another matching.

From there, the reason that $|M \cap N|$ increases is that we remove an edge $f \notin M$, and add an edge $e \in M$. (We know $f \notin M$ because $e \in M$, and $f$ and $e$ share a vertex: two edges in a matching cannot share a vertex.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  For the second question, I still don't understand how we know $f \notin M$

Comment: We know $f \notin M$ because $e \in M$, and $f$ and $e$ share a vertex: two edges in a matching cannot share a vertex.

Comment: slaps forehead* Of course!  Thanks a lot!